# How to create a bigram/trigrams index in Lucene 3.4.0?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I am new to Lucene and I would really appreciate an example on how to have bigrams and trigrams tokens in the index.

I'm using the following code and I have modified it to be able to calculate the term frequencies and weight but I need to do that to bigrams and trigrams also. I can't see the tokenization part! I searched online and some of the suggested classes do not exist in Lucene 3.4.0 as they have been deprecated.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
Moe

EDIT: --------------------------------

Now I'm using the NGramTokenFilter as mbonaci suggested.
This is part of the code where I Tokenize a text to get the uni, bi and trigrams. But it's being done on a character rather than word level.

Instead of:
`[H][e][l][l][o][HE][EL]` etc.

I'm looking for: `[Hello][World][Hello World]`

```
        int min =1;
        int max =3;
        WhitespaceAnalyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
        String text ="hello my world";
        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("Data", new StringReader(text));


        NGramTokenFilter myfilter = new NGramTokenFilter(tokenStream,min,max);
        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute2 = myfilter.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute2 = myfilter.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class)
        while (myfilter.incrementToken()) {
            int startOffset = offsetAttribute2.startOffset();
            int endOffset = offsetAttribute2.endOffset();
            String term = charTermAttribute2.toString();
            System.out.println(term);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look at [shingles](http://lucidworks.com/blog/2010/12/17/whats-a-shingle-in-lucene-parlance/). That article shows how to do it.

Comment: This link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html).

[Here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_0/lucene/contrib/analyzers/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.java?revision=1324900&view=markup) is the source.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to make it on a word level rather than characters. For the text `"Hello My World" I get: [H] [e] [l] [l] [o] [He] [el] [ll] [lo]` etc... instead of `[Hello] [My] [World] [Hello My] [My World] [Hello My World]` etc... I used WhitespaceAnalyzer.